# How to get first and second name of user from Azure AD JWT Claims?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am using following line of code for getting claims from azure ad, but I am unable to get first and second/last name of user.

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
JwtSecurityToken decodedeIdtoken = handler.ReadToken(base64IDToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
var claims = decodedeIdtoken.Claims;
```

Also,I have configured given_name and family_name in token configuration of my application on azure portal.

Kindly suggest possible solution to get first and last name in JWT claim.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that, @Tony Troeff approach will work if you want it in **Azure AD B2C tenant**.
>
> If your use-case is for normal Azure AD tenant, you need to pass **`profile`** scope while
> generating tokens to get **family_name** and **given_name** in JWT
> claims.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

In Token configuration, I added both `family_name` and `given_name` like below:

[image]

Now I generated access token using **authorization code flow** via Postman with **`scope`** as below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: profile openid
code:<code_from_above_Step>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded these tokens by pasting them in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website, both have **`given_name`** and **`family_name`** claims like below:

**ID Token:**

[image]

**Access token:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that the `Given name` and `Surname` claims are returned as a part of the JWT token:
[image: Configuration screenshot]

If these are selected and the authenticated user has associated given name and surname values, the JWT token will include `given_name` and `family_name` inside its payload.

Moreover, if you need to, you can collect these attributes on sign up - the user will be required to enter values for his/her first and last name.
[image: Configuration screenshot]

Then the signup form will look like this (note the `Given name` and `Surname` inputs at the end):
[image]